# Should we flag questions that are not programming related?

Tags: support, flags, scope

Should people flag posts that are not programming related, or just add a comment saying such?

The big red box and text "flag with care" makes me question whether or not this is appropriate use of flags.  I feel like if this is important enough to flag perhaps a fourth option should be in the list specifically for this since it'd be a common reason for flagging.

Comment: What level of rep are you talking about? You mean as an option for those under 3K?

Comment: Add a comment. It's visible to all users and gets back to the OP.

Comment: @random, I have 2366 rep.  I didn't know about the option to vote to close questions as "Not Programming Related" at 3K which answers my question.

Comment: I just hit 3K.  I see "close" link now.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you acquire 3,000 rep, you will be able to vote to close questions as "Not Programming Related." There are plenty of users with sufficient rep to close-vote these types of posts, so please don't flag them for moderator attention. If you currently do not have the power to close-vote, work really hard to acquire it :)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  I'll be at 3K soon.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I feel that "flagging" questions for close-able reasons is the responsibility of +3,000-rep users (i.e. vote to close).

The flagging system isn't really designed to give you voice in areas where you have not earned the experience/reputation. **Flagging is designed to bring quick attention to *egregious* problems that require special/expedient consideration of a moderator.**

"Not programming related" doesn't fit that criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do, please, please, please do not **tag** it as "not-programming-related". This misuse of the tag system is endemic, and it drives me nuts!

Comment: 95% of users don't have access to 'close question'.

Comment: @Chip That's not an excuse to make inappropriate use of the tag system - see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36819/too-many-questions-are-being-closed-as-not-programming-related/36821#36821