# Why do some users move that everything not related to programming to SU?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, superuser

Why do some users move that everything not related to programming to Super User? This even happens to questions about networking concepts. The [not-programming-related](/questions/tagged/not-programming-related) tag has been used around 1887 times. It seems that only a few of such tagged questions get moved to SU.

I'm talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169574/if-a-computer-is-connected-to-internet-via-wireless-and-lan-both-which-way-inter), which I asked with the [not-programming-related](/questions/tagged/not-programming-related) tag. Someone said it's not programming-related, so it should be migrated to SU. Shouldn't we remove the tag, then?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36889/close-not-computer-related-questions-on-stackoverflow-instead-of-migrating-them-t and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18434/why-are-questions-moved-to-superuser and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12687/moving-to-superuser-closure-of-threads and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10219/is-superuser-a-stackoverflow-dumping-ground

Answer (score 4):

This sort of "meta" tagging about the question itself, and not the *topic* of the question, is discouraged. See [Should we flag questions that are not programming related?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37302/should-we-flag-questions-that-are-not-programming-related) for more information on the accepted practice.

There are still (as you've noticed) hundreds of questions tagged "not-programming-related" still existing on Stack Overflow. Eventually these will get cleaned up, but it's a big job and the diamond moderators only have so much time available for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Because those users have read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!
>
> Also, try to refrain from asking questions about Stack Overflow itself unless you absolutely, positively have to. Most programmers don't come here to learn about the intricacies of this site; they come here to get answers to their programming questions. Let's try to help them out by not cluttering up the system with navelgazing meta-discussion. If you want to suggest a feature or discuss how Stack Overflow works, visit our meta-discussion site.
>
> If your question is about …
>
> - networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no source code, ask on Server Fault.
> - general computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super User.
> - web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype.

Answer (score 0):

The tag exists for several reasons: Tags existed before moving posts and people can retag before (with lower rep) they can vote to move.

Comment: But to be clear, the use of those tags are generally discouraged.  They might be banned, eventually (*"You've tagged this question "not-programming-related".  Please wait until you have enough rep to vote to close"*)

Comment: Just because those tags existed doesn't mean they should be propagated.

Comment: Absolutely - I agree the tags shouldn't be used - I was offering a explanation why they appear, not offering reasons to use the tags.